# Sed/Awk replace complex string containing any possible printable character

Tags: bash, shell, awk, replace, sed

I need to replace a complex string that can contain any printable characters. This is a real example pattern that I've been unable to replace using `sed`.

```
<!-- %cmd: for F in $(find ../[09]* -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n" ) | grep -v "^$"; do echo "<li><a href=\"$F\">$F</a></li>"; done -->
```

I'm even using a non-printable sed delimiter in order to avoid conflicts since the original string should be composed only of printable characters:

```
DELIM=$(echo -en "\001");
```

But it doesn't work. I've tried many things, and I can't figure out what I'm  missing. E.g.:

```
echo "BEFORE $PATTERN AFTER" | sed -e "s${DELIM}${PATTERN}${DELIM}NEWTEXT${DELIM}"
```

---

**UPDATE-1:**

The provided solution should print all the lines of the container text, while replacing the matching string with a new one.

```
pattern='<!-- %cmd: for F in $(find ../[0-9]* -maxdepth 0 -type d | sed "s/^\.\.\///"); do echo "<li><a href=\"$F\">$F</a></li>"; done -->'
container='
<h2>Title</h2>
<ul>
    <!-- %cmd: for F in $(find ../[0-9]* -maxdepth 0 -type d | sed "s/^\.\.\///"); do echo "<li><a href=\"$F\">$F</a></li>"; done -->
</ul>
'
```

---

**UPDATE-2:**

After a couple of iterations, this is the working, final and accepted answer built by @anubhava:

```
awk -v repl="newtext" 'FNR==NR {
    a = a $0; next
} n = index($0, a) {
    $0 = substr($0, 1, n-1) repl substr($0, n+length(a))
} 1' < (printf '%s\n' "$pattern") <(printf '%s' "$container")
```

**[Code demo](http://ideone.com/QxPQ7p)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conrol characters in sed's delimiter like this:

```
pattern='foobar'
delim=$'\01'
echo "before $pattern after" | sed "s${delim}${pattern}${delim}newtext${delim}"

before newtext after
```

---

**Update:**

As your pattern contain all sorts of special meta characters, it is better to ditch regex (sed) and use non-regex replacement using `awk`:

```
pattern='<!-- %cmd: for F in $(find ../[09]* -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n" ) | grep -v "^$"; do echo "<li><a href=\"$F\">$F</a></li>"; done -->'

awk -v repl="newtext" 'FNR==NR {
    a = a $0; next
}
n = index($0, a) {
    $0 = substr($0, 1, n-1) repl substr($0, n+length(a))
} 1' <(printf "%s\n" "$pattern") <(echo "before $pattern after")

before newtext after
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/t1s6mt)

Comment: Thanks but replacing `foobar` with the pattern I showed in the question, it doesn't work for me, using Bash 4.3 shell.

Comment: @joseLuís: It works fine with GNU bash version 4.2.8.

Comment: @anubhava I made a fork using with the right pattern, and it doesn't work http://ideone.com/n2aWfv

Comment: @Cyrus I've just compiled bash versions 4.2 and 4.53 to try it and it does not work for me, when using the pattern in question. Like this http://ideone.com/n2aWfv

Comment: @joseLuís: Sorry, unfortunately my mistake! It does not work with my bash. The problem is your $pattern contains multiple characters (round brackets, pipe) which are special for sed.

Comment: No prob. That's fantastic. I can work with that. And I think I'm gonna start learning awk, starting with your solution.

Comment: @anubhava There's only one problem, and it is that when the source text has multiple lines, only the line with the match match gets printed. And I need the whole original string with only the match replaced. Since I don't know awk yet, I'm solving it by replacing newlines before the operation using `tr`, and then replacing them back. But it would be nice if awk could do it all one step.

Comment: Hmm dealing with multiline search/replacement can be very tricky. If you provide me a sample data in question then I can certainly try something and update the answer.

Comment: @anubhava thanks that would be great. I made this simple test example: http://ideone.com/QxPQ7p

Comment: @Edmorton thank you, I tried beating sed into submission before with many scaping patterns, but never really worked. Awk is the only promising tool so far.

I'm not sure if I need to escape the backslashes, because as long as the substitution pattern and the container text expands them it should work for the matching. It does seems to work well right now in that regard, except for the lack of multi-line support. But it's true that escaping them would probably be the safest choice.

Comment: @joseLuís: Try my edited awk command i.e. `awk -v repl="newtext" 'FNR==NR {
    a = a $0; next
}
n = index($0, a) {
    $0 = substr($0, 1, n-1) repl substr($0, n+length(a))
} 1' <(printf "%s\n" "$pattern") <(printf "line 1\nline 2\nbefore %s after\nline 3\nline 4\n" "$pattern")`

Comment: Ok this is fantastic! It works perfectly! Thank you a thousand times @anubhava for your generosity and persistance with this question. I've updated the [code demo](http://ideone.com/QxPQ7p) to show the current status. And in case you're curious the code was intended for a [website static generator](https://github.com/andamira/webera/issues/11) where I attributed your work properly I hope. Shortly I'll update the SO question. And thanks to everyone involved. This has been a great experience.